# How to retrieve data from database developing jira plugin?

Tags: java, database, jira

Im simply developing CRUD Jira plugin using Atlassian-Sd. I have my application on localhost http://localhost:2990/jira, I created simple projects and issues.
In my class I use Active Objects layer.

Im using for example

```
public ExampleEntry getID(String id){
    return ao.get(ExampleEntry.class, 3);
}
```

It's working fine, I have result in my Velocity, but implementing Entity in Jira Api it's a little difficult. Not like in JpaRepository. 
How can I make simple CRUD operations, like get Issue, delete issue, update issue, get list of issue. Thanks for respond